# Is it possible to have one domain that has content hosted on different servers?

Tags: ajax, dns, cross-domain, subdomain, shopify

Currently I have an informational site running on .net and would like to addon ecommerce functionality via shopify. Is it possible to have a site split between two hosted locations/languages but tied together under a single domain?

so it would be wwww.domain.com/store/ instead of store.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use something like nginx or varnish and set backends to the various routes on your site thus merging them together to give the impression that it is all one site.

The issue you may face however would that sessions would not be shared so you'd have problems to have a cart icon with a count of items etc across the entire site.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not familiar with these technologies but will look into them. *I am more designer than developer

Comment: It is going to be an uphill struggle then friend.  This sort of a system is a bit devops heavy.  Doable certainly however it takes some experience to get all the parts to move together.